# Meeting details in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

You can view someone's calendar schedule in MS outlook. It shows what time they are free/busy/tentative. But is there a way we can know the details of their meeting if their calender is booked? for example if a person A is meeting person B, is it possible for person C to know that via outlook? or is it that outlook treats it as a privacy setting and will not let person C view the details?

-Nadel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can manage that with permissions.

Say User B wants to know calendar details of User A. So user A would have to give at least *read permission* for the calendar to user B. Otherwise it is just showing that, there is an entry for that time (as you described).

In User A's Outlook right-click on the calendar, choose "Sharing" (not sure, what the proper English translation is). Here you can set the permissions for individual Outlook users, but you might also try to alter the values for "Standard" and "Anonymous" - *not sure if they would apply to all users in the network*.

Within permissions, users have to have at least the right so **view the folder** and **read elements**.

After setting permissions to calendar, you'd have to set the permission for the root-folder (something like "Inbox for User A"). Here, each user would have to have reading permissions, too, to see the contents of the calendar-folder.

Comment: So it is really a privacy control setting in outlook by which, you can prevent a third party from viewing your schedule details and also you can allow a group of people (like your team) to know the details. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not sure how it works in team scope, but on an per-user-basis this should work. You could also set this permission thing up for the inbox itself, so that users can access each others inboxes (while on leave or etc.). So they would not have to log onto the network with other user's login data.